# Flex 4.5 - addChildToSandboxRoot?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, tooltip, upgrade, flex4.5

In Flex 3.2 I had implemented a tooltip manager and I used the topLevelSystemManager from ISystemManager to add a child to the sandbox root:

The code was as follows:

```
    var sm:ISystemManager = getSystemManager(currentTarget) as ISystemManager;
             sm.topLevelSystemManager.addChildToSandboxRoot("toolTipChildren" , currentToolTip as DisplayObject);
```

In my endeavour to upgrade Flex to 4.5 I discovered that this method does no longer exist.

What's the appropriate way of migrating this piece of code to 4.5?

Part of the ActionScript class is shown here:

```
mx_internal function createTip():void
{
    // Dispatch a "createToolTip" event
    // from the object displaying the tooltip.
    var event:ToolTipEvent =
        new ToolTipEvent(ToolTipEvent.TOOL_TIP_CREATE);
    currentTarget.dispatchEvent(event);

    if (event.toolTip)
        currentToolTip = event.toolTip;
    else
        currentToolTip = new toolTipClass();

    currentToolTip.visible = false;

    var sm:ISystemManager = getSystemManager(currentTarget) as ISystemManager;
             sm.topLevelSystemManager.addChildToSandboxRoot("toolTipChildren", currentToolTip as DisplayObject);
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out I can just use this

```
sm.topLevelSystemManager.toolTipChildren.addChild(currentToolTip as DisplayObject)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the tooltip manager, as explained [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ffe.html).

Comment: so are you saying the ToolTipManageImpl class with the snippet of code I referred to above is not required anymore?